# Merge sort time complexity check

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, big-o, mergesort

#### Hello guys

I was learning about the merge sort so I wrote this function that takes 2 arrays and merges them sorted.

Can someone tell me the time complexity of this function? 
I thought it would be O(n^2) as I am using shift inside a while loop. 
Is that correct or am I missing something here?

```
    const mergeArr = (arr1, arr2) => {
        let mergedArr = [];
        let loops = arr1.length + arr2.length;
    
        while (loops !== 0) {
            if (arr1[0] <= arr2[0] || !arr2[0]) {
                mergedArr.push(arr1[0]);
                arr1.shift();
            } else if (arr1[0] > arr2[0] || !arr1[0]) {
                mergedArr.push(arr2[0]);
                arr2.shift();
            }
            loops--;
        }
        return mergedArr;
    };
```

Comment: `!arr[0]` is not a good way to check that an array is empty. Use `!arr.length` instead. Also you should test that *before* accessing both first elements: `if (!arr2.length || arr1[0] <= arr2[0]) { … } else { … }`.

Comment: "*I thought it would be O(n^2) as I am using shift inside a while loop.*" - yes, that's mostly correct, but to be precise: what does `n` stand for?

Comment: Yea That is correct I will change it to `!arr.length` instead and I will move it to the beginning of the checker thank you very much bergi.
I believe `n` stands for the number of the elements of any array as we split them equally and then merge them back equally.

Comment: Use index variables to make it O(n) where n is the size of the merged array.

Comment: "*I belive n stands for the number of the elements of any array*" - what exactly is "any array"? If I were to call `mergeArr` with `arr1.length` being `0` and `arr2.length` being `x`, what would `n` be? The larger, the smaller, the average?

Comment: I mean when I do integrate this function to the merge sort code it will take two arrays of the same length so n would be the length of one of them, unless the original array length was an odd number it will have to deal with an empty array once, in that case, it will be 1. is that correct ? @Bergi

Comment: @trincot s idea also has the added benefit (besides less time complexity), that you will not change the passed arrays - so if for some reason you needed the original arrays later, you could still access them in their original unchanged form

Comment: @trincot can you give me an example with code in the answers ?

Comment: @AbramBoutros Ah ok, that makes sense that you don't have arrays of different sizes, but when looking only at this function as given you don't have this context with the constraint. See my answer for how you'd formulate it in general.

Comment: @AbramBoutros I think you should [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you want to know how to rewrite it for linear time complexity

Comment: also a minor detail:  `arr1.shift()` will return the removed element ... so you could just do `mergedArr.push(arr1.shift())`

Comment: @Bergi true, and I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case time complexity is indeed O(n²) when `n` represents the total number of values involved -- which will be the size of the output.

To make this algorithm run in linear time, you can use array indices. I'll apply this as a change to your code without changing anything else (as there are several other things that could be rewritten):

```
    const mergeArr = (arr1, arr2) => {
        let mergedArr = [];
        let loops = arr1.length + arr2.length;
        let i = 0;
        let j = 0;
    
        while (loops !== 0) {
            if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j] || j >= arr2.length) {
                mergedArr.push(arr1[i]);
                i++;
            } else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j] || i >= arr1.length) {
                mergedArr.push(arr2[j]);
                j++;
            }
            loops--;
        }
        return mergedArr;
    };
```

Again, there are several improvements possible that do not relate to time complexity, like for instance:

- the `else` part does not need another `if`, as that condition is going to be true, and you really want to execute either of the two cases. So that second case should be unconditional.
- The loop could exit as soon as one of the two input arrays has been consumed, as then you can append the rest of the other array in one statement (after the loop).

Comment: added benefit with this version, is that the passed arrays are not changed (unlike in the version with shift()) - and since arrays are passed by reference, that can be handy, if for some reason you need to again access the original arrays  at a later point

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII That's true.

Thank you very much guys for helping me out.

I will also add the improvements you said trincot thank you for them, hopefully one day I will be at your level guys :D

Answer (score 1):

> What is the time complexity of this function? I thought it would be `O(n²)` as I am using shift inside a while loop.

Yes, that's correct. But this is a good example of a function where it makes sense to express the time complexity in terms of *two* variables, the size of the first array `x` and the size of the second array `y`. Then we can derive the time complexity to be `O((x+y)²)` or `O(max(x,y)²)`, but most accurate would be `O(x²+y²)`. Using a single variable `n` could only mean `n=x+y` or `n=max(x,y)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Bergi for explaining this to me, I see now and understand that I was looking at the Big O wrong,.